# Problems linking tables in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables, for simplicity let's call them table A and table B. Table A contains 2 rows of values, and table B contains 4 rows of values. Table A is linked to Table B through a foreign key constraint, linked to Table B's primary key. However, if I try to run a query selecting every row from both of these columns, for each row in Table A it runs through every row in table B, for example:

- AValue1 - BValue1
- AValue1 - BValue2
- AValue1 - BValue3
- AValue1 - BValue4
- AValue2 - BValue1
- AValue2 - BValue2
- AValue2 - BValue3
- AValue2 - BValue4

Is there a problem with my tables here? Or is it the case of a bad query?

Comment: To get an answer you're probably best off putting the table schemas (anonymised) and the queries you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select a.colA, a.colB, b.colA, b.colB, b.colC, b.coldD from TableA a, TableB b where a.colA=b.colA;

Assuming colA should be primary/foreign key in each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

(Change ColumnValue, NameOfForeignKey and PrimaryKey by the correct column name)

**Solution 1 :**

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnValue, TableB.ColumnValue
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.NameOfForeignKey = TableB.PrimaryKey
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnValue, TableB.ColumnValue
FROM TableA, TableB 
WHERE TableA.NameOfForeignKey = TableB.PrimaryKey
```